# Send jasper-reports report by email only if certain condition is met

Tags: jasperserver

I have a jasperserver deployed and I want to develop a report and only receive the email with it if certain condition related to database is met. ¿Is this possible?

My case is that I need a daily report but only if something unusual has happened and no mail otherwise.

Thank you.